# SQL - Select all posts with comma separated values of categories with relations table between posts and categories

Tags: mysql

I wish to select the posts with the name of the categories with comma separated values like so :

posts table

| id | post_name | post_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first post | first post content |
| 2 | second post | second post content |
| 3 | third post | third post content |

relations table

| relation_id | post_id | cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 |

categories table

| cat_id | cat_name | cat_slug | cat_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat One | catone | lorem ipsum one |
| 2 | Cat Two | cattwo | lorem ipsum two |
| 3 | Cat Three | catthree | lorem ipsum Three |
| 4 | Cat Four | catfour | lorem ipsum Four |
| 5 | Cat Five | catfive | lorem ipsum Five |

Result :

| id | post_name | post_content | cat_slug | cat_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first post | first post content | catone,catfour,catfive | Cat One, Cat Four, Cat Five |
| 2 | second post | second post content | catfour,catfive | Cat Four, Cat Five |
| 3 | third post | third post content | cattwo,catthree | Cat Two, Cat Three |

I've tried group contact with no luck, its working with multiple queries and foreach loop, but I want to know if its possible to achieve this with only one query.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

Did you try a `join` and `group by`?

```
select p.*,
       group_concat(pc.cat_slug) as cat_slugs,
       group_concat(pc.cat_name) as cat_names
from posts p left join
     relations r
     on r.post_id = p.id left join
     post_categories pc
     on pc.cat_id = r.cat_id
group by p.id;
```

Comment: Yes i tried, that way wont work , its not using the relation table in the middle.

Comment: @bmpf_pt . . . I see.  I was confused because I would call the junction table `post_categories` and the reference table `categories`.  Your data model seems to have a different naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm in my case. I also have 2 tables and 1 relation table just like yours. (MSSQL)

```
SELECT
     p.*
    ,STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + c.cat_name
          FROM categories c
          JOIN relations r ON r.post_id=p.id
          WHERE r.cat_id= c.cat_id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as Result
FROM posts p
```